# How Do I Change Perspective Angles When Stacking Sprites?

Tags: python, graphics, pygame, sprite, game-development

I created a sprite stacking preview program in Python using the Pygame library. Offsetting a sprite sheet by -1 pixel on the Y axis creates a 45 degree perspective by default when each cell is stacked over the previous one. I can also get a 0 degree perspective when I set the cell spacing to 0.

There is a web based sprite stacking program, Sprite Stack Studio, that allows the user to choose 0, 45, 60, and 90 degree camera angles. I have also seen a Pico-8 cartridge that allows for a full half-sphere style perspective around an island.

I'm just curious if this is complicated to do, or if I can make some minor modifications to my current program to get the desired perspectives.

My Sprite Sheet:
[image]

Rendered Image:
[image]

Sprite Stack Studio Example:
https://spritestack.io/studio/?cloud_id=349&app=exporter

PICO-8 Island Example:
https://www.lexaloffle.com/bbs/?pid=15116#p

Comment: Can you please clarify exactly you mean by "Sprite Stack".  The links read like each sprite is a "slice" through a 3d object, where each pixel becomes a 3d "voxel".  In which case this is really a 3d projection of a big bunch of 1-unit cubes, one for each pixel.  The ordering of the stack controls the z-order of the voxels.  Does that sound close?  Voxel - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voxel  There's also this software which has a description: https://rezoner.itch.io/spritestack

Comment: There's some example code for PyGame 3D projections here:  http://archive.petercollingridge.co.uk/book/export/html/460  It wont be "Hardware-3D" fast though.

Comment: Yes, basically is a traditional sprite sheet, except multiple cells make up one image that makes a voxel type image. It's a 2D image that looks 3D.

Comment: I don't think 3D principles apply in this case though.

Answer (score 0):

Right, so I had a quick play at this based on this PyGame + OpenGL Tutorial: https://stackabuse.com/advanced-opengl-in-python-with-pygame-and-pyopengl/

This code doesn't work very well, but it *does* convert the sprite-sheet into voxels, and render them into a PyGame window.  It's really, really, *really* slow.  At least for me, I'd guess it's not using hardware 3D at all.  But it does allow the model to be rendered at any angle.

[image: voxelised sprite sheet]

The big problem is it makes 32 * 32 * 19 = **19456** voxels (minus transparent ones).  Optimising the code such that neighbouring voxels of the same colour get merged into a single rectangular voxel would help a lot.

Anyway, perhaps it will give you a nudge towards getting your own solution working.

```
import pygame
import random
from pygame.locals import *

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

DISPLAY_WIDTH   = 800
DISPLAY_HEIGHT  = 800
DISPLAY_SURFACE = DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL

# A Unit Cube from (0,0,0) -> (1,1,1)
cube_vertices = ( (1,1,1),
                  (1,1,0),
                  (1,0,0),
                  (1,0,1),
                  (0,1,1),
                  (0,1,0),
                  (0,0,0),
                  (0,0,1)  )

# The Surfaces making up each face-square
cube_surfaces = ( (0,1,2,3),
                  (3,2,7,6),
                  (6,7,5,4),
                  (4,5,1,0),
                  (1,5,7,2),
                  (4,0,3,6)  )


### Class to hold a cube's worth of verticies
class Cube():
    def __init__( self, xmove, ymove, zmove, colour ):
        global cube_vertices
        self.colour   = colour
        self.vertices = []
        for vert in cube_vertices:
            new_x = vert[0] + xmove
            new_y = vert[1] + ymove
            new_z = vert[2] + zmove
            self.vertices.append( [new_x, new_y, new_z] )

    def drawCube( self ):
        """ Call the openGL function to render the cube """
        global cube_surfaces
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        for surface in cube_surfaces:
            glColor3fv( self.colour )
            for vertex in surface:
                glVertex3fv( self.vertices[ vertex ])
        glEnd()


### Class to convert a 2D sprite sheet into a (huge) set of 
### voxels-per-pixels
class SpriteSheet3D():
    def __init__( self, sheet_filename, sheet_count, sprite_width, sprite_height ):
        self.cube_list = []
        self.image     = pygame.image.load( sheet_filename ).convert_alpha()
        # TODO: sanity check sprite image matches supplied dimensions

        # Iterate through each sheet's pixels creating cubes/voxels
        # TODO: optimise voxels to combine pixels of the same colour into a single, bigger prism
        for z in range( 0, sheet_count ):
            for y in range( 0, sprite_height ):
                for x in range( 0, sprite_width ):
                    offset_x = x + ( z * sprite_width )
                    pixel_colour = self.image.get_at( ( offset_x, y ) )
                    # Only create opaque pixels (Pixels are RGBA)
                    if ( pixel_colour[3] > 128 ):                     # TODO: handle translucent pixels
                        self.createVoxel( x, y, z, pixel_colour )

    def createVoxel( self, x, y, z, pixel_colour ):
        """ Create a 3D Unit-Cube at (x,y,z) """
        # Pygame maps colours 0-255 for RGBA
        # OpenGL maps colour 0-1 for RGB
        gl_colour = ( pixel_colour[0]/255, pixel_colour[1]/255, pixel_colour[2]/255 )
        self.cube_list.append( Cube( x, y, z, gl_colour ) )

    def drawCubes( self ):
        """ Paint all the cubes """
        for cube in self.cube_list:
            cube.drawCube()


### Main
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode( ( DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT ), DISPLAY_SURFACE )
glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST ) 
gluPerspective( 45, DISPLAY_WIDTH/DISPLAY_HEIGHT, 0.1, 200.0 )
glTranslatef( -16, -16, -150 )  # move camera here

sprite_3d = SpriteSheet3D( 'sprite_stack.png', 19, 32, 32 ) 

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    glRotatef( 3.6, 0,1,1 )  # rotate 3.6 degrees about Y and Z-axiz

    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT )
    sprite_3d.drawCubes()
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.wait(1)


pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: My program has a somewhat functional converter where each pixel is saved into a text file with the X, Y, and Z(sprite sheet cell number). The text file also stores the RGBA values. My original idea was to allow RGBA values to be assigned physical properties, like hit points, sound, and so on. I believe I may be hitting my mathematical limit on this project. I was wondering if there is a "dumb" way to at least get set perspective values like 90 or 60 degrees for example without having to convert my sprite sheet into actual 3D cubes.

Comment: Thanks for the time you put into this by the way, what you came up with is really cool and I appreciate it.

Comment: I'm glad you like it - it was a fun question.

Comment: I still think there is an easier way if I want to have set perspectives though. If I could figure out how to get a 90 degree view with the sprite sheet I would be a happy camper.